# Why read files in internal storage need permission?

Tags: android

Here is read code:

```
        try {
          FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("img.png"); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

From device explorer, I ensure img.png file is really exist:
[image]

but error occured,this is logcat:

```
/data/data/xxx.xxx.xxx/files/img.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

As official doc says,

> Unlike the external storage directories,  your app does not require
>   any system permissions to read and write to the internal directories
>   returned by these methods

So why this happened?
.

Comment: if you want to use an image then you can just add it to your drawable folder and access it but if you want an image from the directory of the device then you need to get permission.

Comment: You can also save file in raw or drawable folder

Comment: What permission, this is a file in internal storage.

Comment: I guess that has something to do with linux file permissions. Try to set it readable for group (or for all?).

Comment: It's actually weird.. I have just tried to do the same and it works fine. What Android version\Device do you have? Do you have an ability to check on other version\device?

Comment: Os version is 4.4.4, and I suspect linux file permissions and will try.

Answer (score 1):

I got it, you're trying to add files from the internal directories of your app.
I created the app which makes a random bitmap image in files directory and shares. you can your solution with this code.

Initially, you need to create an XML file in XML directory under 'res' folder. This is the complete structure of my project.

[image: directories]

paste this code in file_provider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

now add provider in AndroidManifest.xml between  tag.

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.myfileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider" />
    </provider>
```

After this move to the MainActivity.java file. I also used a java class bitmap factory which creates a random bitmap. I think you won't need that.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String SHARED_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".myfileprovider";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void share(final View view) throws IOException {
        // Create a random image and save it in private app folder
        final File sharedFile = createFile();

        // Get the shared file's Uri
        final Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, SHARED_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, sharedFile);

        // Create a intent
        final ShareCompat.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setType("image/*")
            .addStream(uri);

        // Start the intent
        final Intent chooserIntent = intentBuilder.createChooserIntent();
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }

    @NonNull
    private File createFile() throws IOException {
        final RandomBitmapFactory bitmapFactory = new RandomBitmapFactory();
        final Bitmap randomBitmap = bitmapFactory.createRandomBitmap();

        final File sharedFile = File.createTempFile("picture", ".png", getFilesDir());
        sharedFile.createNewFile();

        writeBitmap(sharedFile, randomBitmap);
        return sharedFile;
    }

    private static void writeBitmap(final File destination,
                                final Bitmap bitmap) {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(outputStream);
        }
    }

    private static void close(final Closeable closeable) {
        if (closeable == null) return;
        try {
            closeable.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

This is the complete program that read and write the image file to internal directories without any permission.

[image: Image saved in internal]

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

check the permission programatically. when you want to access that file.

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ctx,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
if (permissionCheck== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
 //this means permission is granted and you can do read and write
}else{
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) ctx,
```

new String [{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
    }